# CURLE_RECV_ERROR 56 when trying to open a url with proxy

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have been trying to send curl requests with a proxy. When I send such requests with a POST method, it works fine, but it doesn't work with GET method and I get:

> CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56) - Failure when receiving data from the peer.

Any possible reason why that occurs?

The below code returns this error whereas when I execute it with another url using POST METHOD it works fine.

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST          , 0);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER        , 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS     , 5);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT     , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091016 Firefox/3.5.4');
// curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    , "gender=M");
curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_PROXY          , $proxyUrl);
curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD   , $urlProxyUserPwd);

echo curl_exec($handle);
```

Comment: can you please provide some code? need to see the options passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error message Unable to retrieve feed: cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer while processing feeds, this is due to the network connection being closed while your script is trying to retrieve a response from a remote server.

Can you increase the timeout on the server side(if server is urs)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you always sending requests to a particular server, or it happens always, for different servers?

It is quite possible that the proxy in question requires data to be sent using POST method, instead of GET method.

If you could give us more info, perhaps some error log, we could be of more help.